# GAS userProperties not behaving as expected

Tags: google-apps-script

In the [guide to Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties), it is stated that the User Properties is for data specific to the current user of a script. I have a stand alone app deployed for the user accessing the app. I have used `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` to set some values. And I expect those values be specific to each user; however, every time a user opens the app, the values for that user overwrites the ones for other users. Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const userProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  let userData = JSON.parse(userProps.getProperty('userData'));
  if (!('foo' in userData)) {
    userData = {foo: e.parameters.userData}
    userProps.setProperty('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
  }

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<p>Expected data specific to ${Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();}:</p><p>${userData.foo}`);
}
```

**Expected behavior:**

When deployed as a stand-alone app configured to execute for user accessing the web app, the displayed data must be specific to the user.

**Observed behavior:**

When a new user runs the app, previous users see the data set by the new user, as if the new user's setting has overwritten theirs.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: How did you deploy your app? Did you test new user and previous user on the same browser? Also, your minimal reproducible example is not working. 
The return of `userProps.getProperty('userData')` is a string. Converting it using `JSON.parse` won't work. Which will prompt error on `if (!('foo' in userData)) {`